# Setting up a RANK() on a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following functional query pulling data for a contest.

```
select top 10 AgtInfo.AgtID as AgentID
   ,AgtFN + ' ' + Left(AgtLN, 1) as Name
   ,CAST(ROUND(SUM(case when AppsStatusType IN ('IS', 'CP') then
        (case when AppsInfo.PolicyTypeID in (105, 139) then 
            (case when AppsInfo.AppsEntryDate between '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-30' then (((ColPrem * ModeValue) * 0.07 + (cast(ExcessPrem as decimal(18,2)) * 0.07)) * 2)
            else ((ColPrem * ModeValue) * 0.07 + (cast(ExcessPrem as decimal(18,2)) * 0.07)) end)
        else (case  when AppsInfo.AppsEntryDate between '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-30' then (((ColPrem * ModeValue) + (cast(ExcessPrem as decimal(18,2)) * 0.07)) * 2)
            else((ColPrem * ModeValue) + (cast(ExcessPrem as decimal(18,2)) * 0.07)) end) end)
    else 0 end),2) as MONEY) as IS_CP
   ,CAST(ROUND(SUM(case when AppsStatusType = 'PD' then 
        (case when AppsInfo.PolicyTypeID in (105, 139) then 
            (case when AppsInfo.AppsEntryDate between '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-30' then (((ColPrem * ModeValue) * 0.07 + (cast(ExcessPrem as decimal(18,2)) * 0.07)) * 2)
            else ((ColPrem * ModeValue) * 0.07 + (cast(ExcessPrem as decimal(18,2)) * 0.07)) end)
        else (case  when AppsInfo.AppsEntryDate between '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-30' then (((ColPrem * ModeValue) + (cast(ExcessPrem as decimal(18,2)) * 0.07)) * 2)
            else((ColPrem * ModeValue) + (cast(ExcessPrem as decimal(18,2)) * 0.07)) end) end)
    else 0 end),2) as MONEY) as PD
   ,(case when SUM(case when AppsStatusType IN ('IS', 'CP') then ColPrem else 0 end) >= 10000 then 'Y' else 'N' end) as Qualified
   ,LEFT(GETDATE(), 11) as Date
from TblAppsInfo AppsInfo
inner join TblAgentInfo AgtInfo on AppsInfo.AgtID = AgtInfo.AgtID
inner join TblApplicationStatus_L AppsStatus ON AppsInfo.AppsStatusID = AppsStatus.AppsStatusID
inner join TblClientInfo ClientInfo ON AppsInfo.ClientID = ClientInfo.ClientID
inner join TblCompanyInfo CompInfo ON AppsInfo.CompanyID = CompInfo.CompanyID
inner join TblPolicyTypes_L PolTypes ON AppsInfo.PolicyTypeID = PolTypes.PolicyTypeID
inner join TblDepartment Dept ON CompInfo.DeptID = Dept.DeptID
where AppsInfo.AppsEntryDate >= '2014-07-01'
AND AppsInfo.AppsEntryDate < '2015-01-01'
AND Dept.DeptName = 'life'
group by AgtInfo.AgtID, AgtFN, AgtLN
order by IS_CP DESC, PD DESC
```

This pulls back the following data:

```
AgtID   Name        IS_CP       PD      Qualified   Date
---------------------------------------------------------------
7457    DIANE O     23800.00    6205.76 Y           Aug 21 2014
1137    PAULINE W   7000.00     1604.72 Y           Aug 21 2014
6085    AARON H     3990.00     1486.80 N           Aug 21 2014
8662    LINDSEY H   1578.48     0.00    N           Aug 21 2014
7653    AMBERLY B   1461.20     0.00    N           Aug 21 2014
8733    ANTHONY K   1454.04     339.00  N           Aug 21 2014
7670    TYLER T     1167.20     0.00    N           Aug 21 2014
1344    DANIEL V    990.72      0.00    N           Aug 21 2014
88      JERI W      919.08      0.00    N           Aug 21 2014
7781    CHRISTINE G 826.50      0.00    N           Aug 21 2014
```

What is the easiest way to define a RANK() column within this data set? Would I need to port these results to a temp table before writing them to my final table?

Comment: The easiest way would be to just add a `Rank()` column in your `Select`... but I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The issue with this is that I'm attempting to rank based off of a column I'm creating. SQL doesn't seem to like that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your current query an make it a CTE:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select rank() over (order by is_cp desc) as rank, t.*
from t;
```

Depending on how you define the rank and how it handles ties, you might prefer `row_number()` or `dense_rank()`.